# Ajax - Spring MVC Compilation Error

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

In my spring MVC I use @ResponseBody annotation to create the JSON object & I use AJAX & jquery for query & parsing the data.

Everything works great but we figured out that when our bean object (the one in controller) which we receive from a library changes we have no control over it inside the JSP because it won't provide any compilation error & because we just use Jquery to parse our JSON.

this has made us worry because our bean object may change frequently.

right now these solution came to our mind:

1) when the request came to our controller method, we just use ServletDispatcher to make the content somewhere else (another jsp) & return it back to the user. (This is bad because we have to use row Servlet code inside Spring framework )

2) (trick) we call getter methods of our object inside our controller method & when the content of that object changed, It leads to compilation error inside the controller method.

Do you have any idea or solution that leads to compilation error when the bean object inside the controller change or is there any specific Spring method to solve this problem ?

Comment: Why does your `bean` class change? Under what circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the library bean in another object. Or create a test that validates the serialized JSON.